# Kaggleのデータセットダウンロードにおけるエラー "404 - Not Found - no gcs url" の対処法について

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kaggle

GoogleColaboratoryで"!kaggle competitions download -c painter-by-numbers"というコマンドを実行して、https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/painter-by-numbers/data のデータセットをダウンロードしようとしました。

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

"404 - Not Found - no gcs url"というエラーが発生しました。

**試したこと**

https://www.medi-08-data-06.work/entry/kaggle_api
というサイトで"!kaggle competitions download -c titanic"というコマンドがあり、kaggleの別記事(https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/home-credit-default-risk/overview)のデータセットのダウンロード例がありましたが、こちらは正常に働きました。

1.apiを新規作成
2.https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/painter-by-numbers のコンテストに参加する
3.apiをexpireしたのち新しく作成
4.https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/home-credit-default-risk/overviewのコンテストに参加する
5.!kaggle competitions download -c painter-by-numbers"ではエラー発生、"!kaggle competitions download -c titanic"では正常動作という流れです。api破棄とコンテスト参加に関係はないと思いますが、原因がわかる方教えてください。データサイズが90.51 GBと大きいことが原因なのかもしれません。

可能であれば、google colaboratory上で
!pip install kaggle
cd
mkdir .kaggle
mv kaggle.json .kaggle
!chmod 600 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle competitions download -c painter-by-numbers
など試していただきたいです。

Comment: もし別の原因だったとしても、何か工夫しない限り90GBのデータは扱えないようですよ。単体ではユーザー用には77GBまでらしいです。[Limitations of Google Colab while working with Files](https://neptune.ai/blog/google-colab-dealing-with-files#:~:text=Also%2C%20Colab%20has%20a%20disk,like%20image%20or%20video%20data.) よく分からないことで時間を費やすよりはパソコン等のローカルな環境で試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！ローカル環境で試してみます。